# RESTfull user sessions with Spring and JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can I easily create spring user sessions based on information found in a mySQL database connected with JPA ?

As a simple example lets say I have 2 tables:

**users**

- INT id
- VARCHAR(30) username
- VARCHAR(20) password

**bookmark**

- INT id
- VARCHAR(20) name
- TEXT desctription
- int user **(FK)**

Users will be able to view their bookmarks by requesting the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/bookmarks
```

In this manner I need separate user sessions (authentication not my main priority in this case) to be able to show bookmarks specific to the user.

Another way to go is by accessing bookmark information through:

```
http://localhost:8080/{userId}/bookmarks
```

In this case how can I prevent users from accessing another users' bookmark information ? (Such as preventing user id 1 from accessing user id 2s' bookmarks by using the url http://localhost:8080/2/bookmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use Spring Security to secure your app, you can create custom `UserDetailsService` to read user data for each request from DB. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    protected UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User with email=%s was not found", email));
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Of course assuming that you have JPA entity called `User` implementing UserDetails interface.

With this mechanism you can inject `User` instance into MVC controllers:

```
@GetMapping("/bookmarks")
public List<Bookmark> readBookmarks(Principal principal) {
    User user = (User) principal;
    // read bookmarks code
}
```

You can also read in anywhere in the app via:

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
User user = (User) principal;
```

**REACTION ON COMMENT**:

It is broad topic with a lot of decisions to make. e.g. you may consider using JWT, OAUTH2 or token based based authentication. If you are starting with Spring Security, I recommend to look at their [Guides section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#samples). Especially Spting MVC guide is relevant for you.

Comment: I completed the project as you stated and all seems to be well, but how do I then "login" as a user ?